# Find ids repeating more than 3 times

Tags: java

I need to find the repeatedLateComersId which are repeating more than 3 times. lateComers contains list of Customers which may repeat more than 3 times.

```
 List<Long> repeatedLateComersId=new ArrayList<Long>();
    for (Customer repeatedLateComers : lateComers) {
        repeatedLateComersId.add(repeatedLateComers.getId());
    }
```

Please help me.

Comment: Clarify which list contains all and which list contains ids that are repeating more than 3 times.

Comment: To clarify : do they need to appear three times in succeding order?

Comment: @Khnle-KevinLe i will get list of ids in repeatedLateComersId which may contain ids repeating more than 3 times.  I want to get that list of ids in a new list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When iterating through the list of late comers, check if the current late comer has a frequency greater than 3.  If so, add to the list of repeated late comers.

```
 List<Long> repeatedLateComersId=new ArrayList<Long>();
    for (Customer lateComer: lateComers) {
        if (Collections.frequency(lateComers, lateComer) > 3) {
            repeatedLateComersId.add(lateComer.getId());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Collections#frequency` to find the number of occurrences in collection.

For ex :

```
int i = Collections.frequency(list, "obj"); //This will return String obj's occurrences in list
```

Comment: Wow, what an amazing solution :). Good job

Comment: OP does however mention that only the ids of the elements need to match. Two elements with the same id don't necessarily `equal` each other.

Comment: For that, equals and hashcode needs to implement. I just provide the way to count the occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

Is something like this what you want?

```
Map<Long, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>(); // Tracks how many times each ID is found
List<Long> repeatedLateComersId = new ArrayList<>(); // Final output will be stored here
for (Customer lateComer : lateComers) {
    long id = lateComer.getId();

    // This updates the count:
    Integer count = counts.get(id);
    if (count == null) count = 0;
    count++;
    counts.put(id, count);

    if (count == 3) {
        // When we've encountered this three times, add it to the list
        repeatedLateComersId.add(id);
    }
}
```